# How to use numpy's einsum to take the dot product of an subarray?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-einsum

I have an array with 3 axes:

```
a = [[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], 
     [[9,8,7], [6,5,4], [3,2,1]],
     [[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3]]]
```

And I'd like to use einsum to non-iteratively take the dot product of each vector in 'a' with a matrix:

```
m = [[a, b, c],
     [d, e, f],
     [g, h, i]]
```

like this

```
product = [[dot(m,a[1,1,:]), dot(m,a[1,2,:]), dot(m,a[1,3,:])],
           [dot(m,a[2,1,:]), dot(m,a[2,2,:]), dot(m,a[2,3,:])],
           [dot(m,a[3,1,:]), dot(m,a[3,2,:]), dot(m,a[3,3,:])]]
```

to get an array with the same shape as the initial array 'a'. I've been trying to use einsum, but I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick, assuming you are 'dotting' the last dimension of `m` with the last of `a`:

```
np.einsum('ij,klj->ikl',m,a)
```

Comment: Thanks! That works, but it changes the shape of my initial array from (x, y, z) to (y, z, x).

Comment: It looks like changing "ikl" to "kli" is the fix.

Comment: Yes the indexes in the output array can be rearranged.  Since your dimensions are the same all around, differences in order aren't obvious.